# Getting The Similarity Measure between Lists Of Lists

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning the KNN algorithm. I am currently at the stage where I get the nearest neighbors of my Test Instance by computing the similarity measure again each instance of my training data set. Most of what I have come across online all compare the similarities between sequence of strings or lists of strings, what I have are lists of lists with strings and integers. How can I get the similarity measure of my testInstance against each instance of my training Dataset

```
def getNeighbours(trainingSet,testInstance,K):
distances = []
for x in range (len(trainingSet)):
    dist = distance.levenshtein(testInstance,trainingSet)
    distances.append((trainingSet[x],dist.ratio()))
distances.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(1))
neighbors = []
for x in range(K):
    neighbors.append(distances[x][0])
return neighbors

trainSet = [['low', 'low', 4, 'more', 'med', 'high', 'vgood'],['low', 'low', '5more', 4, 'big', 'low', 'unacc'],['low', 'med', 3, 4, 'med', 'high', 'good']]
test_Instance = ['low', 'med', 3, 4, 'med', 'high', 'good']

neigbors = getNeighbours(trainSet,test_Instance,1)
print(neigbors)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know how to compute similarity between sequence of strings then why not convert your integers to strings?

In your case, converting a data item d to string is done with

```
    str(d)
```

and converting back a data item d to string or integer can be done with:

```
    >>> f = lambda s: int(s) if s.isnumeric() else s
    >>> f('3')
    3
    >>>> f('a')
    'a'
```